# GameContinue() not functioning. should loop back to beginning of main()

Tags: java, loops, program-entry-point

I am currently creating a pig game, and have most functions working.
I need the code to work where if player 1 decides to stop rolling, and player two decides to stop rolling, the game will loop back until one player reaches 20 points. Currently, the code ends after 1 run through.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project3_Part1_Submit {
    static int playerScore = 0;
    static int playerTotal = 0;
    static int dice = 0;
    static final int FINAL_SCORE = 20;
    static int playerTwoScore = 0;
    static int playerTwoTotal = 0;
    static boolean gameOver = false;
    static boolean turnOver = false;
    static char repeat;
    static String input;
    static Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

    static Random rand = new Random();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PlayerOneTurn();
        PlayerTwoTurn();
        GameContinue();
        if (playerTotal >= FINAL_SCORE) {
            System.out.print("Current Score: Player 1 has " + playerTotal);
            System.out.print(", Player 2 has " + playerTwoTotal);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Player 1 wins!");
        }
        if (playerTwoTotal >= FINAL_SCORE) {
            System.out.print("Current Score: Player 1 has " + playerTotal);
            System.out.print(", Player 2 has " + playerTwoTotal);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
        }
    }
    
    public static void PlayerOneTurn() {
        while (turnOver == false) {
            do {
                System.out.print("Player 1 turn total is " + playerTotal);       // welcome line
                System.out.print(". Enter (r)oll or (s)top: ");
                System.out.println("");
                
                input = key.next();                                              // input = next key entered
                repeat = input.charAt(0);
                
                if (repeat == 'r')                                               // if input letter = r
                {
                    dice = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;                                  // set dice to number between 1-6
                    System.out.println("Player 1 rolled: " + dice);              // display number, signifying the amount rolled
                    
                    if (dice == 1)                                               // if the number rolled happens to be 1...
                    {
                        playerScore = 0;                                         // reset score to 0
                        System.out.print("Player 1 lost their turn! ");
                        System.out.print("Player 1 total is " + playerTotal);
                        System.out.println("");
                        return;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        playerScore += dice;                                      // add dice amount to player score
                        
                        System.out.print("Player 1 turn total is " + playerScore);// print out total amount earned 
                        System.out.print(" Enter (r)oll or (s)top: ");             // repeat question
                        System.out.println("");
                        input = key.next();
                        repeat = input.charAt(0);
                        if (playerScore >= 20) {
                            playerTotal = playerScore;
                            gameOver = true;
                            return; 
                        }
                        
                    }
                
                }
                else if (repeat == 's')                                           // if neither option is called
                {
                    return;    
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect entry, please try again");       // prompt retry
                    System.out.println("");
                    input = key.next();
                }
            }while(turnOver == false || dice != 1);
            
            
            playerTotal += playerScore;
            playerScore = 0;
            if (playerTotal >= FINAL_SCORE) {
                // System.out.println("YOU WIN!");
                gameOver = true;
                while (playerTotal >= FINAL_SCORE)
                    ;

                break;
            }
        }       
    }
    
    public static void PlayerTwoTurn() {
        System.out.println("success");
        while (turnOver == false) {
            do {
                System.out.print("Player 2 turn total is " + playerTwoTotal);       // welcome line
                System.out.print(". Enter (r)oll or (s)top: ");
                System.out.println("");
                input = key.next();                                              // input = next key entered
                repeat = input.charAt(0);
                
                if (repeat == 'r')                                               // if input letter = r
                {
                    dice = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;                                  // set dice to number between 1-6
                    System.out.println("Player 2 rolled: " + dice);              // display number, signifying the amount rolled
                    System.out.println("");
                    
                    if (dice == 1)                                               // if the number rolled happens to be 1...
                    {
                        playerTwoScore = 0;                                         // reset score to 0
                        System.out.print("Player 2 lost their turn! ");
                        System.out.print("Player 2 total is " + playerTwoTotal);
                        System.out.println("");
                        return;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        playerTwoScore += dice;                                      // add dice amount to player score
                        
                        System.out.print("Player 2 turn total is " + playerTwoScore);// print out total amount earned 
                        System.out.print(" Enter (r)oll or (s)top: ");            // repeat question.
                        System.out.println("");
                        input = key.next();
                        repeat = input.charAt(0);
                        if (playerTwoScore >= 20) {
                            playerTwoTotal = playerTwoScore;
                            gameOver = true;
                            return; 
                        }
                        
                    }
                
                }
                else if (repeat == 's')                                           // if neither option is called
                {
                    turnOver = true;  
                    return; 
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect entry, please try again");       // prompt retry
                    System.out.println("");
                    input = key.next();
                }
            }while(turnOver == false || dice != 1);
            
            
            playerTwoTotal += playerTwoScore;
            playerTwoScore = 0;
            if (playerTwoTotal >= FINAL_SCORE) {
                // System.out.println("YOU WIN!");
                gameOver = true;
                while (playerTwoTotal >= FINAL_SCORE)
                    ;

                break;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void GameContinue() {
        if (playerTotal < 20 && playerTwoTotal < 20) {                          //if neither players totals or 20 or greater
            PlayerOneTurn(); //go back to playerOne
        }
        else //if either one is 20 or greater
        {
            return; //go to main method and finish
        }
    }
    
}
```

My GameContinue() function is what i created to go loop back to PlayerOne.

```
public static void GameContinue() {
        if (playerTotal < 20 && playerTwoTotal < 20) { //if neither players totals or 20 or greater
            gameOver = false;
            PlayerOneTurn(); //go back to playerOne
        }
        else //if either one is 20 or greater
        {
            return; //go to main method and finish
        }
    }
```

I know calling PlayerOneTurn(); will not loop it  back to the start of the main method. I've tried calling all three methods again like this.

```
public static void GameContinue() {
        if (playerTotal < 20 && playerTwoTotal < 20) { //if neither players totals or 20 or greater
            gameOver = false;
            PlayerOneTurn(); //go back to playerOne
            PlayerTwoTurn();
            GameContinue();
        }
        else //if either one is 20 or greater
        {
            return; //go to main method and finish
        }
    }
```

Obviously that just caused a butload of errors. How should i go about having my code continue to loop back until the if statement in GameContinue() is met?

Comment: how about a `while` loop?

Comment: I actually already tried a couple while loops, should have included that. Generally it produces the same error. Im not sure if i actually have to call the main method or not anymore. I just need it to continue going back to player 1, and then 2, until the conditions are met. Maybe im just bad at creating while loops haha.

Comment: just instead of `PlayerOneTurn();
        PlayerTwoTurn();
        GameContinue();` in your main method use `while(playerTotal < 20 && playerTwoTotal < 20) {PlayerOneTurn();
        PlayerTwoTurn();}` Did that fix your problem?

Comment: I made this while loop... ```public static void GameContinue() {
  while (gameOver = false) { //if neither players totals or 20 or greater
   
   if (playerTotal < 20 && playerTwoTotal < 20) {
    PlayerOneTurn();
    PlayerTwoTurn();
   }
   else {
    gameOver = true;
   }
  }``` It stops the errors, however now its just stopping after the second player holds. I dont know how to post multi line code in comments sorry.

Comment: That's syntactically wrong and unnecessary complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ecto has commented, you could use a `while` loop in the main function. It is shown here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (GameContinue()) {
        PlayerOneTurn();
        PlayerTwoTurn();
    }
    if (playerTotal >= FINAL_SCORE) {
        System.out.print("Current Score: Player 1 has " + playerTotal);
        System.out.print(", Player 2 has " + playerTwoTotal);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Player 1 wins!");
    }
    if (playerTwoTotal >= FINAL_SCORE) {
        System.out.print("Current Score: Player 1 has " + playerTotal);
        System.out.print(", Player 2 has " + playerTwoTotal);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
    }
}
```

Now obviously this would be an error as `GameContinue()` is a void method. To combat this you can change `GameContinue()` to this:

```
public static boolean GameContinue() {
    if (playerTotal < 20 && playerTwoTotal < 20) {
        gameOver = false;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This would solve your problems and your code is minimally changed.

Comment: Yes this does in fact work! the one thing i found that would need to be added is turnOver also needs to be set = to false below gameOver. otherwise it will still continue to stop. like my previous issue.